# Best way to increment Integer in arrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

What is the cleanest way to increment an Integer in an ArrayList?

```
ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
ints.add(5);
ints.add(9);
```

What is the cleanest way to increment the last element?

`ints.set(ints.size() - 1, ints.get(ints.size() - 1) + 1);` seems pretty ugly to me.

Comment: It *is* pretty ugly, but a lot of Java is. I'd consider wrapping it up in a method so your mainline code isn't cluttered.

Comment: I'm with @DaveNewton on this one. I can't see a better way but I'd wrap it up in a method for readability / testability.

Comment: int lastIndex = ints.size() -1;
        int lastValue = ints.get(lastIndex);
        ints.set(lastIndex, lastValue + 1);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you need to use another structure of data?

```
LinkedList<AtomicInteger> ints = new LinkedList<AtomicInteger>();
ints.add(new AtomicInteger(5));
ints.add(new AtomicInteger(9));

ints.getLast().incrementAndGet();
```

Comment: Even though AtomicInteger does not have autoboxing. Using linkedList and atomic integer makes the code much more cleaner

Comment: But coding isn't just about aesthetics. Why use Atomic* is there's no concurrency thing involved. It's unnecessary overhead. Different datastructure usage should be based on use-case Not on looks.

Comment: When you work on a small project - I will agree with you. When you have a team of 400-500 developers... readability and supportability becomes the most important thing. It would be a necessity to use standard structures, even if this means "overhead".

Comment: In that case you'd better create your own class wrapping an int that has increment().
As opposed to have that overhead of AtomicInteger

Answer (score 19):

You can't increment the value in place since `Integer` objects are immutable. You'll have to get the previous value at a specific position in the `ArrayList`, increment the value, and use it to replace the old value in that same position.

```
int index = 42; // whatever index
Integer value = ints.get(index); // get value
value = value + 1; // increment value
ints.set(index, value); // replace value
```

Alternatively, use a mutable integer type, like [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) (or write your own).

Answer (score 2):

I have done something like this:

```
arraylistofint.set(index, arraylistofint.get(index) + 1);
```

here is an example from my code (modified names):

```
ArrayList<Integer> numBsPerA = new ArrayList<> ();
...
int cntAs = 0;
int cntBs = 0;
for ( TypeA a : AnArrayListOfAs )
   {
      numBsPerA.add(0);
      for ( TypeB b : a.getAnArrayListOfBs() )
      {
         numBsPerA.set(cntAs, numBsPerA.get(cntAs) + 1);
         cntBs++;
      }
      System.out.println(a.toString()+ " has "
                        +numBsPerA.get(cntAs)+" TypeBs");
      cntAs++;
   }
   System.out.println("Total number of As: "+cntAs); 
   System.out.println("Total number of Bs: "+cntBs);
   // can now loop over numBsPerA to check how many Bs per A or whatever.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can done by the code using java ...In that we can Increment each element of the list

```
List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
  //int[] primitive = List1.toArray(list1);
  int count=0;
  int count1=0;
  int k=0;
  list.add(3);list.add(2);list.add(3);list.add(5);
  System.out.println("The given input is");
  for(int i:list){
      System.out.println(i);
  }
  Integer[] a = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
  for(int i = 0; i <a.length; i++)
    {
        if(i==a.length-1){
            a[i]++;
            count++;
        }else if(i==a.length-2){
            a[i]++;
            count++;
        }else if(i==a.length-3){
            a[i]++;
            count++;
        }else if(i==a.length-4){
            a[i]++;
            count++;
        }

    }
  System.out.println("After first operation");
  for(int i:a){
      System.out.println(i);
  }

  System.out.println("the first count is"+count);
  for(int i = 0; i <a.length; i++)
    {
        if(i==a.length-1){
            a[i]--;
            count1++;
        }else if(i==a.length-2){
            a[i]--;
            count1++;
        }else if(i==a.length-3){
            a[i]--;
            count1++;
        }else if(i==a.length-4){
            a[i]--;
            count1++;
        }

    }

   for(int i:a){
      System.out.println(i);
  }
   System.out.println("the second count is"+count1);
  //int Count2=count+count1;
   System.out.println("After second operation");



  System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
  for(int j:a){
      System.out.println(j);
  }
 List<Integer> list1=Arrays.asList(a);

  System.out.println("After conversion of list");
  for(int i:list1){
      System.out.println(i);
  }
```

i made the count also...

This question asked in one of the interview also..

Answer (score 0):

1. You may always use plain arrays:

```java
int[] ints = new int[10];

++ints[9];
// or
++ints[ints.length - 1];
```

Note: however, usually, it is safer to stick to the `List`.

2. If you have a lot of incrementing, you can write a small neat code snippet:

```java
private static void increment(List<Integer> list, int ind) {
    list.set(ind, list.get(ind) + 1);
}
```

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(5);
list.add(15);

increment(list, list.size() - 1);
```

Note: even if you need to increment only one time in one function, it may be worth it to have such a snippet for readability.