# Is there a way to add number to existing number in ArrayList in one line?

Tags: java, android

I have an `ArrayList` of integers {1,2,3} and i want to `add` numbers to them. Let's say I want to add 1 and the ArrayList becomes {2,2,3}.

```
int example = arrayList.get(0);
example += number;
arrayList.set(0, example);
```

This is what I have for now... is there better way??

Comment: maybe`arrayList.set(0, arrayList.get(0) + number);`, but better in what?

Comment: No, there isn’t. Another option is to design a mutable integer class and use it in your list instead of the built-in `Integer`. Depending on your circumstances you may also consider an array of integers, an `int[]`.

Comment: Related: [Best way to increment Integer in arrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205268/best-way-to-increment-integer-in-arraylist-in-java).

Comment: Thank you guys! But @DaanSeuntjens and @ YCF_L gave the best answer for my scenario!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do that in 1 line like this:

```
arrayList.set(0, arrayList.get(0) + number);
```

then you don't need an extra variable

Comment: This is perfect!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be overly-complicated:

```
list.subList(0, 1).replaceAll(v -> v + number);
```

Or:

```
ListIterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator();
it.set(it.next() + number);
```

But what you have now is fine.

Comment: Thank you for the effort! But I'm looking for a way to add 1 number to 1 index at a time. Thanks!

Comment: @Simeon that isn't what your question asks, nor what the other answer does.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, if you can tell me a better way.. I will edit it! But I'm happy with the answer.